# what datatype to choose in pgadmin4 to store long text in Postgres instead of 'char varying []'?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes, custom-data-type

I'm storing a title of a post and need to store long text - which is a list of 100 comments for this post. I want to append them altogether and store as a string

in pgadmin4 there is

```
character varying []
```

data type available when creating table.

what other options do i have? create my own custom structure?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with an array? You can *render* the array as a csv etc, but the obvious choice is to store the data in its natural form - an array.

Comment: @Bohemian, I dont know how to store an array as one thing in a column

Comment: Define column as `text[]`. To insert: `insert into ... values (..., '{"str1", "str2", "str3"}', ...)`. See [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/arrays.html)

Comment: Why an array? If you want to "append" them, use a `text` column

Answer (score 3):

`TEXT` data type is the best choice and it's a variable with unlimited length

For more information refer https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html

Comment: "Unlimited" is a bit of an exaggeration: it's limited to 1GB.